# Internet Explorer doesn't start at all

Tags: internet-explorer

Internet Explorer on my phone doesn't start. I can't remember whereupon and exactly when it was started. I noticed it at first time several days ago. Before that browser tabs stoped working.

Phone reboot doesn't help. Hardware search button doesn't work too. All other browsers I found in marketplace work correctly.

Why did this happen? Help me please. Phone without good browser makes me sick.

Comment: Did you make any unsupported thing like install custom ROM, change regkeys? By the way witch phone is it?

Comment: I have SAMSUNG GT-I8350 (Omnia) and I didn't install custom ROM or change regkeys.

Comment: On a while I found two very slick browsers (Baidu Browser, SurfCube) and one honesty good (UC Browser). I will be using they. But it doesn't solve problem with not working hardware search button.

Comment: Very strange. App that open the browser or use the browser control works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try going to settings, swipe over to applications, go to IE and delete history. I had a similar problem (my search button worked) and this fixed it. If you have changed any other settings here, reset them back to the defaults. For example, did you change "Open links in a separate tab"?

you could also always try resetting your phone.

Comment: I don't want reset my phone. Your answer help me another way. When I went in IE settings page I refresh my memory about one option in it - "open links from other apps". Several days ago I changed it form "current tab" to "new tab". This was my fault. After I turned it back search button and Internet Explorer start working fine. 

Thank you for the clue.

Answer (score 1):

First, you can try opening "settings" > Applications > "Internet explorer" and deleting history.

If it doesn't work.. You can reset the phone completely (from settings>About)